# Can't center images in div

Tags: html, css

So I have a div, inside that i have horizontally aligned divs, in this example just 1. Within this horizontal div are 3 divs, one aligned to the left, one middle and one right. I want the images within each of those 3 divs to be centered so it is more visually appealing.

I have tried: margin: 0 auto; but it didn't work, any ideas why this isn't working and how to get it working?

HTML

```
<div id="main">
<div id="firstRow">
    <div class="firEl">
        <img class="logo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg"></img>
        <p>BlahBlahBlah</p>
    </div>
    <div class="secEl">
        <img class="logo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg"></img>
        <p class="elPara">BlahBlahBlahBlahBlah</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thirEl">
        <img class="logo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg"></img>
        <p class="elPara">BlahBlahBlahBlahBlah</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .logo{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#main{
    width: 650px;
    height:650px;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    overflow: auto;
    min-width: 650px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#fff;
}
#firstRow{
    width:650px;
    min-width:650px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#CCC;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.firEl{
    background-color: #FFF;
    min-width: 10px;
    height: 140px;
    width: 100px;
    width: 30%;
    float:left;
    margin: 10px;
}
.secEl{
    background-color: #FFF;
    min-width: 10px;
    height: 140px;
    width: 100px;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 10px;
    float:left;
}
.thirEl{
    background-color: #FFF;
    min-width: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 140px;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 10px;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/genome314/2u695mdu/

Answer (score 3):

Adding this should do the trick:

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or just align center as the other answer below stated, if you want to keep your images inline.

Comment: Been battling with MUI to center an img inside a Box inside a grid item to put it centered on top of some text.
This did the trick for me. Thanks from 5 years into the future.

Answer (score 0):

Give `text-align:center;` in each div css

like:

```
.firEl{
 text-align:center;
}
```

**Edit**

if, text don't want center then:

```
.elPara{
    text-align:left;
}
```

Check your updated code here. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ketan156/2u695mdu/5/)

Comment: I think OP wants images centered. You centered the text too.

Answer (score 0):

set **text-align:center** for each div that contains the logo.

```
#firstRow div{
text-align:center;
}
```

[image: results]

Comment: I think OP wants images centered. You centered the text too.

Answer (score 0):

I threw in Nick Solloum's answer and found that the logos were still a little off center towards the bottom.  I made all your image classes into one since they had the same values anyway.  I fixed this by changing padding-top: to 4% and found it looked much cleaner to me.  Here is the adjusted CSS.  I hope this helps

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='so.css'>
</body>
<div id="main">
<div id="firstRow">
    <div class="El">
        <img class="logo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg"></img>
        <p>BlahBlahBlah</p>
    </div>
    <div class="El">
        <img class="logo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg"></img>
        <p class="elPara">BlahBlahBlahBlahBlah</p>
    </div>
    <div class="El">
        <img class="logo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg"></img>
        <p class="elPara">BlahBlahBlahBlahBlah</p>
    </div>
</div>



</html>
```

CSS

```
  .logo{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#main{
    width: 650px;
    height:650px;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    overflow: auto;
    min-width: 650px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#fff;
}
#firstRow{
    width:650px;
    min-width:650px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#CCC;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.El{
    background-color: #FFF;
    min-width: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 140px;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 10px;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 4%;
}
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

Add display block to `.logo`. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/2u695mdu/4/

**CSS**

```
.logo{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#main{
    width: 650px;
    height:650px;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    overflow: auto;
    min-width: 650px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#fff;
}
#firstRow{
    width:650px;
    min-width:650px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#CCC;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.firEl{
    background-color: #FFF;
    min-width: 10px;
    height: 140px;
    width: 100px;
    width: 30%;
    float:left;
    margin: 10px;
}
.secEl{
    background-color: #FFF;
    min-width: 10px;
    height: 140px;
    width: 100px;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 10px;
    float:left;
}
.thirEl{
    background-color: #FFF;
    min-width: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 140px;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 10px;
    float:left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="firstRow">
        <div class="firEl">
            <img class="logo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg"></img>
            <p>BlahBlahBlah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="secEl">
            <img class="logo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg"></img>
            <p class="elPara">BlahBlahBlahBlahBlah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="thirEl">
            <img class="logo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg"></img>
            <p class="elPara">BlahBlahBlahBlahBlah</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Only the image is centered.

**Method 2**

Add `<div align="center">` before each image, as here: http://jsfiddle.net/2u695mdu/7/

**Method 3**

Check `@ketan` answer.

**Method 4**

Because you setted the image width, you can use, postion relative to images as here http://jsfiddle.net/2u695mdu/8/

```
.logo{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
display: block;
margin: auto;
```

instead of

```
margin:0 auto;
```